# Why do we use Provider and useContext when we can use just a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs

Why do we use Provider and useContext when we can use just a custom hook?

i.e I have a custom hook that provides user data and login/logout fn:

```
export default function useAuth() {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null)
    const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  
    const logout = () => {}
    const login = () => {}
  
    useEffect(() => {
     // do auth stuff
     // setUserInfo({...})
     // setLoggedIn(true)
    }, [])

  return { userInfo, logout, login, isLoggedIn }
}
```

I guess I can create AuthProvider and then get access to these values via useContext in my components.

What's the difference between using just useAuth() instead of using useContext within AuthProvider?

I guess It's better to use the second approach because useAuth() will run with useEffect on every component where I'm calling it where I can run useEffect only once in AuthProvider and share the retrieved state with useContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom hooks solve the problem of boiler plate code. If yours is not a library and you are not going to resuse the custom hook again, why waste to bundle it as a separate file or custom hook?

If you beleive your `useAuth()`, used only once, which seems ideal as authentication is done only once, no need for custom hook in my opinion. Over engineering isn't good and remember YAGNI pronciple.